# Mutiple controllers mapped to one Spring websocket

Tags: spring-boot, stomp, spring-websocket

I have a question related to Spring websockets with the STOMP protocol over it.
I'm using websockets for different application but not with the combination of Spring.

I have a client server application that holds multiple websockets connections to the server. Now can I create a client application that connects to the Websocket of Spring (with STOMP). Also can I map one websocket to multiple controllers in Spring? The data for every controller is different. So for example my client sends data to the server and set something a value to say, the data need to be send to controller X. Can Spring automaticly transfer the data to the correct controller?

The image below show a POC for my question. The client does send different messages to the Spring server using a websocket connection. Now for every message the controller need to be changed. So for example for message X the controller X need to handle the request and for message Y the controller Y need to handle the request.

How can I achieve this using Spring websockets using STOMP?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need use microservices and Spring Cloud. https://spring.io/blog/2015/07/14/microservices-with-spring

The main WebServer need connect to other servers with different functionalities. It is a transactional services.